# persistence of SEIR epidemic model

Tags: stochastic-processes, dynamical-systems, mathematical-modeling, biology, mathematical-biology

We have the following stochastic SEIR model
$dS=\Lambda - \beta SI - \mu S - \sigma SI dB(t)$
$dE=\beta SI - (\lambda +\mu) E+\sigma SI dB(t)$
$dI=\lambda E-(\gamma +\alpha +\mu) I$
$dR=\gamma I-\mu R$

The initial conditions $S_0,E_0,I_0,R_0$ are all positives

By using itô's formula about $lnE(t)$, i found

$dlnE(t)=\left(\frac{\beta SI}{E}-(\lambda +\mu)-\frac{1}{2}\frac{\sigma^2\beta S^2I^2}{E^2}\right)dt+\frac{\sigma SI}{E}dB(t)$

For the persistence of the disease I saw in some paper that
As $R_0>1$ , thus when $t$ tends to infinite, it has that $E(t)$ and $I(t)$ in average are $E*$ and $I*$, so that

$\frac{\beta SI}{E}=\frac{\beta SI*}{E*}$

Where $I*$ and $E*$ are the endemic equilibrium point and $R_0$,is the reproduction number of the deterministic SEIR system.

I did not understand exactly this process, and is there another way to study the persistence